# highchars not showing in ipad or iPad resolution

Tags: ipad, twitter-bootstrap, highcharts

I'm building a kind of Dashboard application with Bar charts and some simple tables showing the reports. We want this application to be working on Iphone and iPad, but when the iPad is on horizontal mode nothing will show up, just a grey box, but as soon as I flip my iPad to vertical mode the data shows up. 
This also happens when I resize the window to iPad-like resolution. It works just fine in mobile tho.

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and PHP to build the project. Has anybody heard of this?

What the chars looks like at full screen
[image: What the chars looks like at full screen]

What the charts look like when the window is resized to iPad like resolution, the container turns gray, but if I resize to a lower res, it displays just fine, only iPad-like resolution (also happens in android, windows, mac) its the resolution.
[image: What the charts look like when the window is resized to iPad like resolution]

This is my actual script:

```
<script>
$(function () {
        $('#fchart').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Report 2014',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: domain.com',
                x: -20
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Q1<br>Oct - Dec', 'Q2<br>Jan - March', 'Q3<br>April - June', 'Q4<br>July - Sep']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Total Actions'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ''
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    minPointLength: 3
                }
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Impressions',
                data: [0,2557337,0,0],
                visible: false
            }, {
                name: 'Clicks',
                data: [0,6456,0,0]
            }, {
                name: 'Frequency',
                data: [0.00,11.88,0.00,0.00]
            }, {
                name: 'Engagement',
                data: [0,639,0,0]
            }, {
                name: 'Likes',
                data: [0,4410,0,0]
            }, {
                name: 'Clicks',
                data: [0,115,0,0]
            }, {
                name: 'data',
                data: [0,748865,0,0],
                visible: false
            }]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: How we can replicate this issue ? Could you apply it as live demo ?

Comment: I run this example http://jsfiddle.net/Zc2pA/ and flip on the iPad from vertical to horizotnal and back, problem doesnt appear.